# Unsure of the meaning of $F=ma$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

If I strike an object with mass $1$ kg with a force of $1$ N (let's say in space), would that object continue to travel in space with an acceleration of $1$ $m/s^2$? My intuition suggests that it would continue travelling at some constant velocity. If it were accelerating, where would it get the energy to keep going faster and faster? What does $F=ma$ actually mean?

Comment: For how long do you plan to apply this force?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F=ma$ is a definition, if you like. It says that 1 N of force is defined as making a mass of 1 kg accelerate at 1 m/s², meaning that for every second the force is applied, the mass goes 1 m/s faster.

The reason the time the force is applied matters is that if you apply the force for 2 seconds, the speed increases by 2 × (1 m/s), etc. Once the force stops, so does the acceleration, at which point the mass continues at whatever velocity it was accelerated to.

Comment: So, $Ft = mv $? what is mv?

Comment: Ft = mv - mu where v is the final speed and u is the initial. This is because a = (v-u)/t. Also mass x velocity is momentum so it essentially says Ft = (change in momentum).

Answer (score 1):

Newton's second law $\sum \vec F=m\vec a$, means that the sum of the external forces on an object are directly proportional to the acceleration the object undergoes; where the constant of proportionality is the mass of course.
When a force is applied to a body, it continues to experience an acceleration for the duration of the application of force. When an object is "struck" with a force, like say a billiard, force is applied to the object only over a short time interval during witch it is accelerated. This change of momentum is known as impulse and is given by:$$\Delta \vec p=\int_{t_i}^{t_f} \vec F\;dt.$$
Thus, ignoring dissipative effects, the billiard experiences a force due to the impingement of the cue stick, it is accelerated with a resultant change in momentum, after which it continues with uniform motion, i.e. at rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a force of 1 Newton steadily over a period of $t$ seconds, your 1-kg mass will accelerate at 1 $m/s^2$ for $t$ seconds, thereby achieving a velocity of $t$ meters per second, which it maintains unless and until it encounters another force.

If $t=0$ (that is, if you imagine applying your force for "just an instant") then your mass remains at rest.  If this conflicts with your intuition, it's because your intuition is falsely telling you that it's possible to apply a force for "just an instant".

Comment: So. hypothetically, if I attach a jet engine which constantly spits out fuel at 1 N, that would cause the mass to continue accelerating?

Comment: Also when I say i strike, im referncingg let's say a baseball being hit by a bat

Comment: Physics does have a way to describe forces applied for an instant: [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_%28physics%29). We use this regularly to describe things like hitting a nail with a hammer or a ball with a bat, where the force is very strong but applied very briefly so despite the time being near 0, the change in momentum is non-zero.